# Why is my array not being accessed by an included file?

Tags: php

I'm working on a site from scratch. Partially as practice and to help a friend. One of the things I'm doing is creating the menu dynamically off of plugins and modules that we create. My current config defines the base files and then the user plugin is supposed to be able to push more data into the array.
What I have currently is

```
<?php
function Deny() {
if(!defined("__directaccess")) {
  header("Location: /");
  }
}
Deny();
$Plugins = array("Bootstrap", "MySQL", "User");
$menuItems = array (
  "Home"  => "/",
);
```

And that's inside my config.php file.
Within my User.class.php file which is successfully loaded with the plugin loader I've built I have

```
require_once(__root.'/config.php');
$menu = array (
  "User Panel"  => "/index.php?page=user",
  "Logout" => "/index.php?page=login&module=logout",
);
print_r($menuItems);
```

`$menuItems` Gives that it's not defined.
I've checked with a simple `echo "Included";` script inside the config.php file to ensure that it's being included, but at the `$menuItems` we fail out. What I want to happen is after the Menu has been generated I'll be able to push more data into the menuItems array so that modules/plugins can add to the menu as well and use variables within those functions to make the navigation seamless. Any help would be appreciated as I'm stumped as I don't understand why it can't access the array.

Load order to help see what's going on
`index.php`

```
LoadPlugins($Plugins);
LoadModule("TopNav");
LoadPages();
```

`loader.php`

```
session_start();
define("__directaccess", true);

require_once("config.php");
//Loads All Class Functions
function LoadClasses() {
    foreach(glob(__class.'/*.class.php') as $class) {
    if(file_exists($class)) {
        require_once($class);
        }
    }
}

function LoadPlugins($Plugins) {
foreach($Plugins as $Plugin) {
  LoadPlugin($Plugin);
    }
}


function LoadPages() {
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        if(file_exists(__root. '/includes/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php')) {
            require_once(__root. '/includes/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php');
    } else {
        echo "Page not Found"; //Make a 404 Error Page
    }
}
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            if(file_exists(__root . '/includes/homepage.php')) {
                require_once(__root . '/includes/homepage.php');
            }
    }
}


function LoadModule($moduleName, $page="index") {
    $path = __modules . '/' . $moduleName . '/' . $page . '.php';
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            require_once($path);
        } else {
            echo "Failed to Load module " . $moduleName;
        }
}

function LoadPlugin($pluginName) {
    $path = __plugins . '/' . $pluginName . '/' . $pluginName . '.class.php';
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        require_once($path);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to load plugin " . $pluginName;
    }
}
```

The `$menuItems` array is first created in the `config.php` file and then the plugins are loaded. The thought is that the plugins should be able to access variables from within the config.php file with that format.

`Full User.class.php`

```
$menu = array (
  "User Panel"  => "/index.php?page=user",
  "Logout" => "/index.php?page=login&module=logout",
);

print_r($menuItems);

function __isOnline() {
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  return true;
  } else {
  return false;
  }
}

class UserFunctions extends webConn {
  public function userDetails($arg, $username) {
    $query = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = :username
SQL;
    $resource = $this->db->prepare( $query );
    $resource->execute( array (
      ":username" => $username,
    ));
    $result = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result[$arg];
  }
}
$userFunction = new UserFunctions();
```

`config.php with SQL Database info Removed`

```
<?php
function Deny() {
if(!defined("__directaccess")) {
  header("Location: /");
  exit();
  }
}
//Deny();
$Plugins = array("Bootstrap", "MySQL", "User");
$menuItems = array (
  "Home"  => "/",
);





//Create a root directory base name to reference
define('__root', dirname(__file__));
//Create Class Reference Global Variable
define('__class', __root . '/classes');
//Create Module reference
define('__modules', __root.'/modules');
//Create Plugin reference
define('__plugins', __root.'/plugins');
```

Comment: As a separate aside, you need to put `exit();` straight after your `header` command in the config file, otherwise anyone you want to deny access to this script to will indeed be redirected, but the current PHP script will carry on executing anyway, and if they want to they can easily look in the browser's Network tool to see the rest of the content they were supposedly denied access to. Or they can use a tool like postman to view it. So you really need to stop the script from executing as soon as you've determined that access should be denied.

Comment: Thanks for the tip there @ADyson I thought header location acted as a ```die()``` as well

Comment: No, not sure where you got that idea? `header()` literally just sets a HTTP response header, that's all. You wouldn't want it to automatically die during that, because there are lots of other types of header you can set which don't involve redirection and wouldn't need the script to stop, and/or you might want to issue several header() commands to set several headers for the same response. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Where is „ __directaccess“ defined? Try without deny(); if your array is accessible.

Comment: ```__directaccess``` is defined in the ```loader.php``` file that loads the plugins and modules. Unfortuantely it's the same result with the ```Deny()``` function commented out. I can access all constants defined within the config file, but the variables are inaccessible by the user plugin

Comment: Does the code of User.class.php you posted have been simplified?

Comment: I've gone ahead and included the entirety of user.class.php to the question

Comment: Wow, what a mess. This is all over the place, and not following common good OOP practices at all. For example you actual user class file, should contain the class only - and nothing else. And despite the file being named `User.class.php`, the class apparently isn't even actually named `User` ...

Comment: Learnin' as I go, drive a truck for a living, but thanks for the constructive? criticism.

Comment: So is `require_once(__root.'/config.php');` now part of your `User.class.php` file, or is it not? You first say it was, but then what you show as `Full User.class.php` doesn't appear to contain that line any more?

Comment: Was removed to see if I could still access anything from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `require/include` inside a function, the scope is the function itself.

For example the following function

```
function LoadClasses() {
    require_once($class);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function LoadClasses() {
    print_r($menuItems);
}
```

That's why `$menuItems` is null. To fix the problem, you can use `global` keyword to always refer a global variable.

```
gloabl $menuItems;
print_r($menuItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @shingo, had a comment above and I see what the guy means, so got some cleaning up to do on the code as well haha.